# Internal memory not showing after Marshmallow update

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow

Upgraded my Yuphoria to Ressurection Remix Marshmallow rom. There was an option to use my memory card as internal storage. I clicked it and migrated data to it. After this, I'm not able to view my internal storage in file explorers. I can see how much GB is used under settings but not by ES explore. Anyone know why is this happening?

[image: ES Explore]

[image: Memory used under settings]